# How to handle list item events from client side using JSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, client-object-model

My requirement is like - When an item is added to a list, a log should be added to another list? And this needs be done using JSOM. is there a way to achieve this using JSOM?

Comment: There are many ways of adding items to a List (QuickEdit, REST, etc.) Are you factoring all these things into your requirements?

Comment: My requirement is not adding list item, but to handle the event when the item is added

Comment: why are you not using workflows? Is there any specific reason?

Comment: JSOM is not an appropriate way to handle this scenario, for the reasons jasonscript has noted.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your scenario is O365, the standard approach would be to use Remote Receivers. Those xan be attached to the list and perform operations when events occur, such as adding, removing, modifying, etc.

The following post is a good starting point:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220043.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here:
1.) Use Jquery to add an additional click event on Submit button and write JS code to make entry to the log list.
To achieve this simply add a content editor on you new item form.
Something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527783/call-submit-button-function-from-jquery

2.) Use the Pre save event of Sharepoint
https://deannaschneider.wordpress.com/2012/12/03/sp2010-using-presaveaction-on-custom-forms/

Comment: Neither of these approaches will work for quick edit, nor will they work for list items created programmatically.

Comment: He wanted to do it using JSOM seems like he does not have option to do programming.